# How can I resolve a time() vs microtime() problem?

Tags: php, time

I am trying to start several processes as close to the same time as possible.  A cronjob selects all items to be processed from the database a minute prior to the actual time these processes need to start, and then starts a child process for each record found.

As it can take several seconds to run through the database and spawn the child processes, I am trying to create a sleep or usleep delay so that each spawned child process starts as close as possible to the top of the next minute.

In testing, I have noticed some differences between the child start times returned by time() and microtime().

Here's the code I have to create the delay:

```
$unixtime_now = time();
$unixMicrotime_now = microtime(true);

$timeToStart = $unixtime_now + 2;
$timeToSleep = $timeToStart - $unixMicrotime_now;
$timeToSleep = number_format($timeToSleep,6);
$timeToSleep = str_replace('.','',$timeToSleep);

usleep ($timeToSleep);

$startedAtMicrotimeFloat = microtime(true);
$startedAtTime = time();

$date1 = date("H:i:s", $startedAtMicrotimeFloat);
$date2 = date("H:i:s", $startedAtTime);

echo "Unixtime Now = $unixtime_now<br />UnixMicroTime Now = $unixMicrotime_now<br />Time to Start = $timeToStart<br />Time to Sleep = $timeToSleep<br />Started at Time = $startedAtTime - $date2<br />Started at MicroTimeFloat = $startedAtMicrotimeFloat - $date1";
```

Note that I used 2 seconds rather than 60 seconds for the offset to facilitate speed in testing.

2 questions:

1) No matter how many times I run this, the times returned by time() are ALWAYS 1 second before the times returned by microtime().  For example:

```
Started at Time = 1555765444 - 09:04:04
Started at MicroTimeFloat = 1555765445.0002 - 09:04:05
```

This is probably a forest for the trees issue, but does anyone have an idea why this is or how I can resolve it?

2) Are there any drawbacks to having a usleep() delay that can be as long as 59 seconds?  Would it be better to use sleep() and accept the the child processes might start at 1555765445.9999 - 09:04:05 rather than 1555765445.0002 - 09:04:05, or up to almost a full second later?

Thanks in advance.

Alan

---

Per Dave's suggestion, I edited the code as follows:

```
$date1 = date("H:i:s", microtime(true));
$date2 = date("H:i:s", time());
```

I still get the same result:

```
Started at Time = 1555876342 - 15:52:22
Started at MicroTimeFloat = 1555876343.0003 - 15:52:23
```

The microtime() result, which I suspect to be accurate, is later than the time() result by 1.0003 seconds.

Comment: What do you get if you move your retrieval of times into the variable assignments for `$date1` and `$date2`? Simply calling `time` and `microtime(true)` I have been unable to reproduce a difference between them at a seconds level. It's probably also worth asking what version of PHP you are using. And is there a reason why you are trying to start things at the same time or near the start of a minute?

Comment: I will try your suggestion when near a computer again... may be a few days.  It’s a process to automate what has previously been a manual process.  I want to give each of my subscribers an equal chance at getting one of a limited quantity of tickets when the ticket window opens

Comment: Dave... see above

Comment: What version of PHP on what platform? As I said I haven't been able to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 and PHP 7.2.17.  If I might ask, do you get the same result with both time and microtime? Thanks

Comment: Yes, consistently using Windows and PHP 7.3.4.